# Why am I getting error 'TypeError: string indices must be integers'

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have the JSON file below, and I am getting an error

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "test11.py", line 10, in <module>
>     print(driver['id'])
> TypeError: string indices must be integers
> ```

```
{"drivers": 
    [
        {
            "id": "91907", 
            "groupId": "9039", 
            "vehicleId": "11111", 
            "currentVehicleId": "11111", 
            "username": "ablahblah", 
            "name": "Andrew Blahblah"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have written the follow code to extract out values from the
file

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

with open('driver.json', 'r') as f:
    drivers_dict = json.load(f)

for driver in drivers_dict:
    print(driver['id'])
    print(driver['groupId'])
    print(driver['vehicleId'])
    print(driver['username'])
    print(driver['name'])
```

I need help to understand why I am getting the error and how to fix it.

Comment: You are attempting to index a string with another string. Consider wrapping the ID string in `int`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately, the problem is that looping over a dict gives you the keys.

```
>>> [i for i in drivers_dict]
['drivers']
```

I think you just got your json layout confused. This works:

```
import json

with open('driver.json') as f:
    j = json.load(f)

drivers_list = j["drivers"]

for driver in drivers_list:
    # BTW you can DRY this part:
    for key in ['id', 'groupId', 'vehicleId', 'username', 'name']:
        print(driver[key])
```

Answer (score 0):

Also Consider checking if the id is string or integer.
`isinstance(s, str)`